# Blender texture links on document transfer

Tags: texturing, linked-data

Blender Users!

I'd like to ask for your opinion/input on the following issue:
I've bought a new laptop and will have to transfer all my files from old one to new one accordingly. On a new laptop the user folder name is different, and cannot be changed now without dull manipulations I would like to avoid.
I imagine that once files are transfered, even into same places (it's Windows to Windows shift), all the textures in Blender will be unlinked because of that different user folder name.
Or they won't?

If they will, is there a possibility to embed textures directly into Blender file without creating FBX? Did someone try this? Does this file become super heavy and destroy the PC?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Best!
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you have all your textures and resources saved in one folder then you could zip that folder and move it to the new computer, do the same with the .blend files, if any of the image files become unlinked then just open blender go to File > External Data > Find Missing Files, then just go to the folder you saved them to and they should just pop back into place. [image]

You could also pack all of your textures into your blend files and that would work but it would also make your files bigger since the texture is now saved inside of the .blend file,

Depending on how many textures are in the .blend file it will take longer to open, however the pictures will be there no matter if the original folder holding the pictures gets deleted or if the .blend file itself is moved to another computer without the original pictures. if you still want to do it this way, open blender, top left File > External Data > Pack Resources and all external files will be packed. [image]

I would still recommend zipping and porting the folder where you save all the image textures and such and moving that to the new computer regardless of whether you pack the images in the file not so that you don't loose your images.
I hope this helps a bit. Good luck

Comment: Note that if you have been using Relative Paths in your blend files, then all you need to do is make sure that the Blend files are in the same relative position in your folders when you move everything.  In that case you won't have to find missing.

Comment: Thank you so much! My main problem is that some projects have a huge amount of different textures, so zipping-unzipping and relinking them would take quite a time... But I assume in such case I don't necessarily need to zip the folders? If I'm transferring all the data from one PC to another, I can relink textures in the same way as if I zipped the folders. Or not?

I will also try to pack textures and see what happens. I'm required to deliver some projects on USB flash, so it will have to be done anyways.